# Skipping current directory and previous directory using luafilesystem dir iterator

Tags: lua, luafilesystem

In LuaFileSystem, `lfs.dir(<path>)` iterates over the contents of a directory as strings. If I wanted to print the attributes of the contents of a directory, I might do it like this (using inspect.lua to print a human readable table representation):

```
for name in lfs.dir(<path>) do
    local path = <path> .. '/' .. name
    inspect(lfs.attributes(path))
end
```

However, the first two strings from the iterator seem to always be `'.'` and `'..'` (the shell notation for current directory and previous directory).
This causes errors in my code as `<path> .. '/' .. '.'` is never a file or directory.

I've begun skipping these by advancing the state twice before looping.

```
local it, state = lfs.dir(path)
state:next()
state:next()
for file_name, _ in it, state, nil do
    -- stuff
end
```

The advantage is that I do not have to explicitly check to see if the string is `'.'` or `'..'` for each iteration. One disadvantage is a decrease in readability.
Will there ever be a case where the first two strings are different?

Answer (score 1):

You can just be explicit about it:

```
for name in lfs.dir(<path>) do
    if name ~= '.' and name ~= '..' then
        local path = <path> .. '/' .. name
        inspect(lfs.attributes(path))
    end
end
```

Comment: That is what I am trying to avoid. I may need to reconsider.